# How to set number of processes in MPI in VisualStudio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpi

When I press start in VisualStudio my MPI project executes only with one process.

I can build it and then run in console

> mpiexec.exe -n 4 program.exe

and program running with 4 processes. But I want to be able to debug it.

Where/How can I set an option for number of processes in VS?

Comment: You need to change the code, and update appropriate `MPI_*` function call

Comment: @Ajay No, this has nothing to do with the calls inside the application.

Comment: Then what is `mpiexec.exe` ? I don't think it is relevant to VS

Comment: Please note that MPI is about having multiple processes (also called ranks), not threads. I fixed it in your question,  but make sure to not confuse the two.

Comment: @Ajay, I told that mpiexec.exe is my workaroud, but it's unuseful and I want to know better way. It really has no relation to VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are separate processes, not threads. So as far as I can see there are two options:

1. Start processes running, look at the ids in process explorer and attach VS debugger to selected one.
2. Try to use windbg, along the lines

   ```
   mpiexec.exe -n 4 windbg program.exe
   ```

(it might need launching via `start`)